# object segmentation with bwlabel

Tags: image, matlab

I have a binary image and I am interested to do segmentation only in the characters that appear in the horizontal central line, because applying bwlabel on the whole image returns 80 objects to me, but **I am interested the only in characters whose pixels appear in the center line.**

if I apply bwlabel to the central subimg line, I get 9 objects, of these I have to discard the first character that is on the left, of the remaining 9-1, I have to select the N (f.e N=6) those that have the largest area ( sorting and selection).

I did something like:

```
% Ib1 = binaryImage;

off = height / 2;
Ib2 = Ib1 (off-2: off + 2, :);
[Ietiq, NumObj] = bwlabel (Ib2);

stats = regionprops (Ietiq, 'Area', 'Centroid');
areas_matlab = cat (1, stats.Area);
centroid_matlab = cat (1, stats.Centroid);
areas_matlab = sort (areas_matlab, 'descend');
```

I don't know how to select only the largest N objects and segment these objects, detected by the horizontal center line (only a part of the pixels that make up the character) on the initial image Ib1.

thanks to those who will be able to help me

Comment: could you please provide a sample image?

Answer (score 1):

Matlab's 'sort' function has a second argument that provide an array of the elements' indices describing the arrangement of the sorted elements. You can slice it by N to get the desired N largest connected components out of regionprops.

it should look like this :

```
[areas_matlab, ii] = sort (areas_matlab, 'descend')
N=6;
max_n_stats=stats(ii(1:N));
```

**EDIT:**
To visualize the result - add the 'PixelIdxList' feature to regionprops function call and draw the selected characters:

```
Ib22 = zeros(size(Ib2));
for ii=1:N
    Ib22(max_n_stats(ii).PixelIdxList) = ii;
end

Ib11 = zeros(size(Ib1));
Ib11(off-2: off + 2) = Ib22;
```

Comment: BTW, you can replace -
areas_matlab = cat (1, stats.Area) --> areas_matlab = [stats.Area];

Comment: thanks, but how can I visualize / label these N objects (with larger area) on the starting image Ib1?